Why is προσκυνέω translated as "worship" only when applied to God but not when applied to men?
I have noticed a consistent bias in English translations of the scriptures, both old and new. Whenever the Greek προσκυνέω or the Hebrew וַיִּשְׁתַּ֖חוּ appear (in their various conjugations), if the word is applied to God proper or to "a god," then the word is translated as "worship." However, if the term is applied to your average man then it is translated as the more literal and mundane "to bow down, to prostrate oneself."
A great example of this is Exodus 18:7 (NASB)

Then Moses went out to meet his father-in-law, and he bowed down and kissed him; and they asked each other about their welfare, and went into the tent.

If you review the Hebrew, the word translated here as "bowed down" is וַיִּשְׁתַּ֙חוּ֙. And if we look at the Greek of this verse in the Septuagint, the word is προσεκύνησεν, the 3rd person singular aorist active indicative conjugation of the aforementioned προσκυνέω.
But when these words are applied to God, we see they are translated as "worship." For example, 1 Samuel 15:31 (NASB)

So Samuel went back following Saul, and Saul worshiped the Lord.

The Hebrew word here is again וַיִּשְׁתַּ֥חוּ, while the Greek from the Septuagint is again προσεκύνησεν; the exact same as for when Moses "bowed down" to Jethro.
As far as I can tell, this distinction is entirely artificial and has been abused by translators to falsely build up the case for the Trinity by selectively translating the Greek word as "worship" when applied to Christ, just as when it is applied to God proper or to "a god," and not translating it in the same manner as when applied to men. For example...
Matthew 28:16-17

16 But the eleven disciples proceeded to Galilee, to the mountain which Jesus had designated to them. 17 And when they saw Him, they worshiped Him; but some were doubtful.

The Greek word translated as "they worshiped" is, of course, προσεκύνησαν. This is nearly identical to the word used when Moses "bowed down" to Jethro - only it is 3rd person plural instead of 3rd person singular.
On to my question... While it appears to me that the above practice is an abuse by translators to force their biases upon the unsuspecting reader, I want to know if there is in fact a good, objective reason for this practice. Any references you can provide to substantiate your answer would be much appreciated.

Isn't this a Bible Hermeneutics question?

You might consider looking at a verse like Psalm 95:6, where both bow down and worship are used together. See what words are used there in the Septuagint for each, and in the Hebrew if you're so inclined.

Strong's Greek 4352 says the following in regards to the word προσκυνέω (Transl.: proskuneó)

Usage: The Greek verb "proskuneó" primarily means to worship or to
show reverence, often through physical gestures such as bowing down or
prostrating oneself. In the New Testament, it is used to describe acts
of worship directed towards God, Jesus Christ, or, in some contexts,
false gods or idols. The term conveys a deep sense of reverence,
adoration, and submission to a higher authority.
Cultural and Historical Background: In ancient Greek culture,
"proskuneó" was a common practice of showing respect and homage,
especially towards deities and rulers. This act often involved bowing
or prostrating oneself as a sign of submission and reverence. In the
Jewish context, worship was directed exclusively towards Yahweh, and
the physical act of bowing was a significant expression of devotion
and humility. The early Christians adopted this term to express their
worship of Jesus Christ, emphasizing His divine nature and authority.

Bowing down to show reverence was an act of showing respect to persons in Authority positions. Jesus himself uses the term in his parable of the Unforgiving Servant who owed his master (or Lord: kyrios is the word used) a huge sum of money:

"Therefore the kingdom of heaven is like a certain king who wanted
to settle accounts with his servants. And when he had begun to settle
accounts, one was brought to him who owed him ten thousand talents.
But as he was not able to pay, his master (greek: ho kyrios - the
lord) commanded that he be sold, with his wife and children and all
that he had, and that payment be made. The servant therefore fell
down before him (greek: prosekynei), saying, ‘Master, have
patience with me, and I will pay you all.’" - Matthew 18:23-26 (NKJV) - Emphasis mine

The servant "fell down before him", him being his king and lord/master. We see that in this context, proskuneó is not a form of worship, but a display of reverence shown towards a person in high status and authority.
What about the occurrences, where people make an act of proskuneó towards Jesus?
Following texts are all taken from NKJV:

Matthew 2:2 - “Where is the one who has been born KING of the Jews? We saw his star when it rose and have come to worship
(proskuneó) him.”

We see that the translaters used "worship" to translate proskuneó, whereas the context clearly shows that the magi did not want to proskuneó to the child Jesus to worship (there is no indication whatsoever that they thought Jesus was God), but that they wanted to show reverence to the child because he has been born KING of the Jews! So "worship" is a misleading translation here.

Matthew 2:8 - And he [Herod] sent them to Bethlehem and said, “Go and search carefully for the young Child, and when you have found Him,
bring back word to me, that I may come and worship (proskuneó) Him
also.”

Same thing as with the magi - Herod was just told by the scribes that "a ruler" would come out of Judah (Matthew 2:6) - Herod pretended that he wanted to show reverence to this ruler - not worship him. Herod was not told that Jesus were God! Hence another misleading translation of the word.
Matthew 2:11 talks about the same Magi than before having found Jesus an doing the act of proskuneó - the context hasn't changed - they still thought of Jesus being the King of the Jews and not God, hence "worship" is another misleading translation here.

Matthew 8:2 - And behold, a leper came and worshiped (proskuneó) Him, saying, “Lord, if You are willing, You can make me clean.”

The leper addresses Jesus as "Lord" and not as "God". Again, no indication here that the leper believed Jesus to be God, but believing that Jesus was Lord in that he had authority to judge and to heal. Hence, another misleading translation here.

Matthew 9:18 - While He [Jesus] spoke these things to them, behold, a ruler came and worshiped (proskuneó) Him, saying, “My
daughter has just died, but come and lay Your hand on her and she will
live.”

This ruler must have received proskuneó from others, so this was not new to him. Only this time he was the one doing the act of proskuneó towards Jesus. Did he take Jesus for God? There is nothing in the text that indicates this to be the case. As stated in Strongs cultural background: This act often involved bowing or prostrating oneself as a sign of submission and reverence. We see nothing more here. Again a misleading translation!

Matthew 14:33 - Then those who were in the boat came and worshiped (proskuneó) Him, saying, “Truly You are the Son of God.”

The disciples just were eyewitnesses of Jesus walking on water, helping Peter to do the same and calming a violent storm. Of course they were in awe of what they just witnessed. What did they say though when bowing down to Jesus? “Truly You are God.”? Nope - they recognized him as the Messiah, the Son of God. If that is not a clear indication of showing reverence - and nothing more - I don't know what is. Again, a misleading translation.

Matthew 15:25 - Then she came and worshiped (proskuneó) Him, saying, “Lord, help me!”

The woman previously called Jesus "O Lord, Son of David!" (Matthew 15:22) thereby recognizing his designated kingship. She calls him "Lord" not "God". She recognizes Jesus authority, shows the appropriate reverence. Translating this with "worship" is indeed misleading!

Matthew 20:20 - Then the mother of Zebedee’s sons came to Him with her sons, kneeling down (proskuneó) and asking something from Him.

A proper contextual translation of the word here in the NKJV - correcting the misleading translation in the KJV!

Matthew 28:9,10 - And as they went to tell His disciples, behold, Jesus met them, saying, “Rejoice!” So they came and held Him by the
feet and worshiped (proskuneó) Him. Then Jesus said to them, “Do
not be afraid. Go and tell My brethren to go to Galilee, and there
they will see Me.”

Jesus has been resurrected from the dead and has left his tomb. An angel speaks to the women and tells them that they will soon find the resurrected Jesus. When they finally see him, him even saying "Rejoice!", they do an act of proskuneó. Is this worship, or reverence for the proven Messiah, who has totally fulfilled his mission, and provided the means for salvation? You are the judge - I recon it again depends if you identify Jesus being God Almighty in the flesh (in which case you would think that the women worshipped him), or if you believe he is the Son of God Almighty, the Messiah, the Lord and King (in which case it's a case of bowing down in reverence to Jesus).
Well luckily, the end of the same chapter gives us more context we can use, to decide what meaning of the word is appropriate.

Matthew 28:16-18 - Then the eleven disciples went away into Galilee,
to the mountain which Jesus had appointed for them. When they saw Him,
they worshiped (proskuneó) Him; but some doubted. And Jesus came and spoke to
them, saying, “All authority has been given to Me in heaven and on
earth.

So Jesus accepts the proskuneó as he says that: All authority has been given to Me in heaven and on earth - if the disciples and previously the women would have taken Jesus to be God Almighty in the flesh, this statement would have not made sense. Doesn't God Almighty inherently have "All authority in heaven and on earth"? Jesus said that he was GIVEN it only after his resurrection - and because of this authority, validated and visibly proven by the resurrection, Jesus' disciples and the women did an act of proskuneó which in this context means nothing more than prostrating in reverence and homage.
If you read the gospel of John, you will see that Jesus often made use of the term proskuneó, and in his case, it is mostly mentioned in relation to an act given towards the Father (John 4:20-24), whom Jesus identifies as his Father and the God of the Jews (John 8:54), which can be no one else than YHWH/Jehovah. In that case, "worship" is indeed a proper translation.
One can say conclusively that "worship" is an inappropriate translation when used in connection with humans that don't claim to be God Almighty, and "showing respect and homage" is more appropriate based on this context.
proskuneó in context of the Father, God Almighty YHWH/Jehovah, as well as false Gods/deities, is appropriately translated with "worship".

A very valid answer from the perspective of the witnesses. :)

Great answer  I’d quibble a bit with saying that “worship” is only applicable to God; at the end of the day it is the same underlying action being performed. But overall a solid analysis of how context has been ignored in favor of doctrine when translating the book of Matthew!

It seems to be a language thing.
"Proskuneo" can also be translated “worship (in the broad sense),” “venerate,” “fall down in reverence,” “do obeisance”
Greek Orthodox are trinitarians so we interpret it as worship of the Divine.
You're correct that the word used in Matthew 2:11, as well as the other verses you mentioned, is broader than only being able to used to refer to worship of the Divine, the Greek word is a form of the word prosekynēsen which means to bow and make obeisance, essentially veneration or a gesture of deep respect.
But Orthodox and other churches are not trinitarian because of Matthew 2:11 (or the other verse) we're trinitarian because the entire testimony of the Scriptures when read and understood together and with our Christian tradition leads to the conclusion that Jesus Christ is Divine.

There are instances when proskuneo is reserved for God (Exodus 20:5 LXX, Acts 10:25, Rev. 22:9) and others when proskuneo can be properly offered to creatures as derivative icons of God (1 Chronicles 29:20 LXX, 1 Kings 2:13 LXX, Rev. 3:9). Hence, although ‘all honor, glory and worship are due to God,’ relative honor, glory and worship are due to parents, rulers, bishops, angels, saints, etc....


Again, when offering salutations to the life-giving Cross, we together sing: We reverence (προσκυνῶμεν), your cross, O Lord, and we also reverence (προσκυνῶμεν) the spear which opened the life-giving side of your goodness. This is clearly but a salutation, and is so called, and its character is evinced by our touching the things mentioned with our lips. We grant that the word προσκύνησις is frequently found in the Divine Scriptures and in the writings of our learned and holy Fathers for the worship in spirit (ἐπὶ της ἐν πνεύματι λατρείας), since, being a word of many significations, it may be used to express that kind of reverence which is service. As there is also the veneration of honour, love and fear. In this sense it is, that we venerate your glorious and most noble majesty. So also there is another veneration which comes of fear alone, thus Jacob venerated Esau. Then there is the veneration of gratitude, as Abraham reverenced the sons of Heth, for the field which he received from them for a burying place for Sarah his wife. And finally, those looking to obtain some gift, venerate those who are above them, as Jacob venerated Pharaoh. Therefore because this term has these many significations, the Divine Scriptures teaching us, You shall venerate the Lord your God, and him only shall you serve, says simply that veneration is to be given to God, but does not add the word only; for veneration being a word of wide meaning is an ambiguous term; but it goes on to say you shall serve (λατρεύσεις) him only, for to God alone do we render LATRIA. -2nd Council of Nicaea (The Letter of the Synod to the Emperor and Empress)


In conclusion, this is not a translator error or bias. This was resolved during an ecumenical council over 1000 years ago. It is proper to make the distinction while translating to properly differentiate between the multiple meanings of the word. Thus, all Proskuneo would be properly translated as if it was Latria if it is referring to God.
To use legalistic terms.  It would be "Letter of the law" to translate it literally, but "spirit of the law" understanding should include the understanding of the ecumencial councils.

Translating so as to agree with the decisions of “ecumenical” councils would, in fact, be a bias. You’ve just rephrased the bias I pointed out in the OP. It is also worth noting that some of the oldest English Translations - like the Wycliffe Bible and the Douay-Rheims Bible - translate it as worship even when applied to men such as in Exodus 18:7. Albeit both of these were translated from the Latin Vulgate. Nevertheless, both are definitely less than 1000 years old and subsequent to the councils in question.

@RyanPierceWilliams It seems like a vital aspect of translation is to translate the meaning of the words in question. Not just "google translate" them literally. Least we draw icons of Moses with horns (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Moses_San_Pietro_in_Vincoli.jpg) or somehow cause the Taiping rebellion due to a similar character in a name. ... Proskuneo within the context of the worship of the Divine was defined as being understood as Latria. Similar to how in english we have Worship for God, but we venerate Icons, the cross, etc.

to translate the word consistently either as the abstract act of worship or as the actual physical act of bowing down would be correct in any and all cases. It isn’t less accurate to say that a person bowed down to the Lord than it is to say they worshipped him, if anything it is more accurate. Nor is there an error in saying that Moses worshiped his father-in-law, or that any other man worshiped another man. For to worship is to honor someone - which is precisely what the physical act of bowing down conveys.

however, even if I were to for the sake of argument concede that worship should only be used of God / gods / idols / etc. That would still not address the issue of bias in the translation. Jesus was a man and the Son of God. He certainly never refers to himself as God. In the context of the book of Matthew he is never referred to as God, and thus there is no valid reason within that context to translate it as “worship.” The translator is approaching Matthew with preconceived doctrines and making interpretatative decisions based upon those biases.

@RyanPierceWilliams If by "preconceived" you are referring to the understanding that Jesus is indeed God the Son.... as clearly understood since the nicene creed. Then I guess so. You can translate the Bible in a way that makes the fundamental concepts of the Faith harder to understand in english. If we are remaining faithful to the teaching and tradition of the apostles (who clearly believed Christ is LORD) and those who wrote the new testament used language in everyday use... then I don't see the issue with translating the word appropriately into worship or prostration or homage.

Biased translations in favor of the Trinity - specifically of the word “worship” - is precisely the matter which my question concerns. The scriptures were around long before the councils took place. To read later terminology and doctrine into the scriptures is an anachronism that perverts what the original author’s meaning. An unbiased translation will make every effort to communicate what the author wrote - not cater to interpretations put forth by councils several hundreds of years later.

@RyanPierceWilliams Did you forget the tag "unitarian" or something similar? Currently your question appears like you want answers from any denomination and doctrine. If this is not the case, you should have been more specific that you wanted answers that you wanted to hear. But the comments section is not the place to debate, my answer is based on understanding that the teaching of the apostles preceded the new testament, that church tradition is valid, and that the ecumencial councils were not in error when they clarified the understanding of "worship".

it’s not a denomination specific question. It’s a question about objective biases in the translations common across denominations.

@RyanPierceWilliams I wonder what will happen when a new language gets confused about what we were talking about the tools for archery as a verb, or why we thought of a poisonous metal as a positive thing about what a leader does. Why we thought of the seasons when we cook... maybe those future people who attempt to translate our works and writings, will understand that some words had multiple meanings and do their best to understand the context.

You have not presented any evidence to suggest that there is contextual evidence which objectively leads to these translations. I would welcome such evidence. In fact, it’s precisely what I asked for in the OP.

@RyanPierceWilliams I cited an ecumenical council who understood the language better then you or I. But I suppose I can find more. :)

If you’ve studied the debates of the 4th century and onward, you’d know a big part of those debates involved creating and refining new terminology to describe their theological concepts which they derived from scripture and Greek Philosophy. They also came to redefine existing biblical terms to suite their theologies. Just because they spoke the language doesn’t mean their approach to the scriptures was legitimate. They effectively rewrote scripture by teaching people to read it in a manner contrary to the original meaning.

for example: you don’t even think about the contradiction in both saying that Jesus is God and the Son of God. You even add to that God the Son! Since when has a son ever been their own father?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
